# How can I remove "please wait..." from a form?

Tags: 7, forms, rating

I saw this [Remove the "Please wait" text on Ajax Call](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11032/remove-the-please-wait-text-on-ajax-call) but I can't find the form element. `<?php dsm($form);?>` and `<?php dpm($form);?>` return errors. This is what I found in $node:

[image]

I may have missed it. I tried using the ID path in the unset form function but it didn't work. This is what I'm putting in template.php:

```
function fivestar_form_fivestar_custom_widget_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  unset($form['field_funny']['#ajax']['progress']['message']);
}
```

I also tried theme_fivestar_form . . .

Comment: You might want to adjust your module `weight` or check for `after_build`

Comment: @NikhilM can this be done in template.php?

Comment: Can't check it right now and give you the exact selector, but it's easiest to do this through CSS.

Answer (score -1):

this can be done in css:

```
.fivestar-widget .ajax-progress
{
    display:none;
}
```